# php directory traversal issue

Tags: php, security

Hi
We have some php code using the file_get_contents() function, and I understand this is vulnerable to direcoty traversel attacks. Given the following code:

```
$mydata=$_GET['thefile'];
$data = file_get_contents ('/var/html'.$file);
echo $data
```

How can I do some simple input filtering so I can block the posibility that someone might do directory traversel by playing around with my input?

/MR

Comment: Where is `$file` getting set?

Comment: I think your concern is about preventing access to relative paths (e.g. "/path/to/somedir/../../../etc/passwd"), right?

Comment: Correct, the main issue here is as you point out access to relative paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php):

```
$mydata = basename(realpath($_GET['thefile']));
```

---

Appended to (slight modifications of) your example:

```
$file=$_GET['thefile']; 
$mypath='/var/www/';
$location= basename(realpath($mypath.$file));
$data = file_get_contents($location);
echo $data;
```

Note... although this does some level of error checking, it does no error handling.  I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: @zerkms - Then I'm missing something... that's exactly what basename does.  I just tested it.

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike: yep, this could work if OP don't need to specify nested directories like `asd/file.html`

Comment: @zerkms - Sweet... I was getting confused.  : )

Comment: @John Green - PageSpike: yep, I was not enough attentive - that is why I twice added and deleted after a moment my comments ;-)

Comment: So how would basename() prevent access to relative paths? I get I'm missing something here :-) Wouldn't I get access to a relative path still if ../ was used as input in the variable $_GET?

Comment: That's what basename does... gets the filename+ext without any path info.  Similarly, you could use pathinfo(), which separates the path into many components (including basename, filename, extension, and dirname), but I thought I'd make it simple with the single call.

Comment: So if someone might try something like $mydata = basename(/var/www/html($_GET['../bin/binary'])); $mydata would still in effect be /var/html/binary , and "../bin" parth of the file variable would be ignored?

Comment: Mostly correct.  It'll actually be '/var/www/htmlbinary', since you're missing a trailing slash on your base directory string.

Comment: So this would be correct implements you basename function correctly:
$file=$_GET['thefile'];
$mypath=/var/www/;
$data= basename($mypath($file));
echo $data;

Comment: yes, I see and understand. By doing some modifications myself on the previouse comment, would this work?:
$file=$_GET['thefile'];
$mypath=/var/www/
$data= basename($mypath.$file)
echo $data

Comment: No... two issues there.  1).  you need to quote mypath.  2).  You still need to file_get_contents() on the basename results.  You may want to push it through realpath() as well, which provides for some extra security.  I'll modify my example closer to this new pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If the `$_GET['thefile']` won't use folders like "images/fileX.jpg" you can use [basename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php)

```
$filename = basename($_GET['thefile']);
readfile('/var/html/'.$filename);
```

When '../../passwords.txt' is given as `$_GET['thefile']` it will be converted by `basename` to 'passwords.txt'.
Adding `realpath()` inside a basename doesn't add any security.

If your script does need to support subdirectories then use [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to determine if it's inside the '/var/html' directory.

```
$baseDir = realpath('/var/html/'); // (mayby /var/html is a symlink)
$baseDirLength = strlen($baseDir);
$filepath = realpath('/var/html/'.$_GET['thefile']);
if (substr($filepath, 0, $baseDirLength) == $baseDir) {
   // Even when all the '../' in the thefile are resolved 
   // the path is within the $baseDir
} else {
  // invalid $_GET['thefile']
}
```