# Forcing file-creation in public directory?

Tags: php, security, file-io, filesystems, chmod

Here's an idea. I'm trying to create file from PHP script. File may be created in any public place on server (in public root or in its subdirectories). Bottom of line, I want to write function like this (it must work on both unix and windows servers).

```
function create_file($path, $filename, $content, $overwrite=false) {
  # body
  ...

  }
```

**Parameters:**

- **$path** - file-path (empty or ends with `/`)
- **$filename** - any valid file-name (requires dot+extension)
- **$content** - file-content (anything)
- **$overwrite** - if set **true**, existing file will be overwritten (default. **false**).

**Result:**

Function returns `TRUE` and creates file with content, or `FALSE` if file-creation was not possible for any reason.

**Description of problem:**

I expect this function to return `true` and create file **$filename** on path **$path**, or `false` if it wasn't possible for any reason. Also if file was successfully opened for writing, need to put **$content** in it.

Argument **$path** is relative path to public directory, and **$filename** is any valid filename. Of course, I want to avoid creating files if path points **outside of public directory**. Function may be called from subdirectory-scripts like this example

```
# php script: /scripts/test.php
create_file('../data/', 'test.info', 'some contents');
# result file: /data/test.info
```

**What have I tried so far?**

I’ve tried doing this with [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [fwrite()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) functions and that works on some servers, and doesn’t work on some. I guess there’s problem with writing privileges and [chmod()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php) but to be honest I’m not very familiar with chmod attributes. Also I couldn't check if **$path** points outside of server's public directory.

In short, I want this function to create file and return `TRUE` if file doesn't exist, or file exists and `$owerwrite=true`. Otherwise, nothing happens and function returns `FALSE`.

Additionally, I would like to know reason why file can't be created on some path (just in theory). Incorrect path/filename is only thing I have on my mind and I'm sure there's more about this problem.

Thanks in advance for any sample/example/suggestion.

### update code

So far I have this code...

```
  function create_file($path, $filename, $content, $overwrite=false) {
    $reldir = explode('/', trim(str_replace('\\', '/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])), '/'));
    $dirdepth = sizeof($reldir);
    $rpadd = $dirdepth > 0 ? '(\.\./){0,' . $dirdepth . '}' : '';
    $ptpath = '#^/?' . $rpadd . '([a-z0-9]\w*/)*$#i';
    $ptname = '/^[a-z]\w*\.[a-z0-9]+$/i'; 
    if ($res = preg_match($ptpath, $path) && preg_match($ptname, $filename)) {
      $res = false;
      if ($overwrite === true || !file_exists($path.$filename)) {
        if ($f = @fopen($path.$filename, 'w')) {
          fwrite($f, $content);
          fclose($f);
          $res = true;
          }
        }
      }
    return $res;
    }
```

Comment: file can't be created for several reasons: wrong permissions, disk full, disk mounted Read Only, mount point is not present anymore, if is a network share there may be something on the net, disk is damaged, file system has problems .. kernel problems ..  many many other things. About limiting file positions under public dir, you can of course prepend the public path to given path, then check if some ".." is present in file path and in that case return false.

Comment: @kappa, thanks for info. btw, ".." is also valid part of `$path` argument but only if it doesn't point outside of public dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

1. set the owner of the web server document root: chown -R apache:apache /var/www (i suppose /var/www is your document root and that the web server apache runs with user apache). Set the privilegies of the document root like this in order to have all directories under document look with privilegies 755 (only owner which is user apache can write in folders /var/www and sub folders)
2. Block paths that point out of your /var/www document root: you are under the issue known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack. What about if the $path is something like: /var/www/../../../etc/passwd?
   Basename php function can help you identifying this kind of malignous paths. Look this post: [php directory traversal issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085496/php-directory-traversal-issue)
3. To check wheter a file already exists or not: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: This is really bad advice! `chmod -R 755` will make **all files** writable by PHP, not just the directories! It would then take just one file-related vulnerability to allow the attacker to *rewrite your code*!

Comment: @Jon you are right. the -R option is dangerous: the 755 applies only on DIRECTORIES! for files in these directory 555 should be good enough!

Comment: 1) I understand but function body is all I have, other config/settings are not allowed. Everything must be done inside this function (course, if possible). 2) path "/var/www/../../../etc/passwd?" is obviously incorrect because it points outside of public dir (function must return false in that case). 3) i know that. +1 for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

All file functions in php will not work properly in two circumstances

1. If you don't have enough user privileges for applications, then
2. You may not used/passed the arguements/parameters correctly .